# Tesla coil(SSTC)

Tags: microcontroller

I'm designing a Tesla coil and through online tutorials, I have seen people using microcontroller like myrio, stm32 etc. instead of using this controller can I use FPGA for my project

Comment: Seems like an XY problem: why do you think an FPGA is better? What should the FPGA do?

Comment: As someone who has been building Tesla coils for a while, start simple for your first project.

Comment: Using an FPGA is definitely overcomplicating things. Start simple.

Answer (score 0):

Sure a decent FPGA is the best, if you intend to make the best DRSSTC controller. It has to have an all digital PLL (ADPLL), some comparators to detect ZCS, some fast ADC to detect current and voltage peaks (obviously isolated, or at least very high impedance).

Then you have to also do a good current transformer, that it has near constant leading time on most of the range and frequency, you do implement some discrete delay time for the ADPLL, so that you get a true ZCS, resonant converter. Then some known method to skip pulses, once the LC tank voltage or current hits the limit.

A small MCU in the FPGA is needed for display, external control signals, tuning and system identification.

Have you already seen this:

- [Cypress mixed signal MCU/FPGA by Netzpufscher](https://highvoltageforum.net/index.php?action=profile;area=showposts;sa=messages;u=160)
- [ADPLL for induction heating by Hyvok](https://github.com/Hyvok/HardHeat)

Answer (score -1):

If you must use an  FPGA the simplest way is to implement an MCU in the FPGA (such as the NIOS II for Intel/Altera devices) and use that.